# Dynamic drop down value is not chaining based on index in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am creating one html table with dynamic textbox and dropdown control. i am getting one drop down item text based on row, column and cell from db table. I have one gridview with employee list. when I click on first employee,  data populate correctly in dropdown and textbox. But when I click second time on some other employee, text box data is populating not drop down. Dropdown keeps the old value, its not selecting actual value. help is appreciated. Please check my code below.

```
    DropDownList ddl = CreateDropdownList(appraisalsecid, titleid, k, l);
    string objvalue = "";

    var obj1 = dsempvalues.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("SectionId") == appraisalsecid && (x.Field<int>("TitleId") == titleid) && (x.Field<int>("RowId") == k && (x.Field<int>("CellId") == l)));

    foreach (var dr in obj1)
        objvalue = dr["appraisalvalue"].ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objvalue))
    {
        if (ddl.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ddl.Items.Contains(ddl.Items.FindByText(objvalue)))
            {

                ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByText(objvalue));
            }
        }
    }

 if (appraislsubmit)
  ddl.Enabled = false;// this is make probledm
      tc.Controls.Add(ddl);
       tc.Width = "100";
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        allddl.Add(ddl.ID);
public DropDownList CreateDropdownList(int i, int j, int k, int l)
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    try
    {

        ddl.ID = "ddl" + "_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString() + "_" + k.ToString() + "_" + l.ToString();
        ddl.CssClass = "select2-chosen";
        ddl.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = Session["DSDll"] as DataSet;
        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---select----", "0"));
        return ddl;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return ddl;
}
```

some what i found the problem.but i don't know why its happening.if ddl makes disable, drop down not refreshing. if its enabling its working nicely.

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: @anugus can you check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disabled any dropdownlist , then you just need to bind the value you want to it.

Another way,you can bind entire list and then remove others when you want to disable it.